# Jquery draggable not working in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i am trying to create a page here with a table having the property of being dragged. the code is a bit messy but here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".smsSecond").draggable();
      });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="topLogo">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/logo_big.png"  height="50" width="310"/></a>
        </div>
        <div id="topLogoR">
            <img src="images/right logo.png"  height="60" width="300"/><br/>
            <font color="#335599">Logged in as XXXXXXXXXX: </font>
            <select>
                <option value="online"><font color="#335599">Online</font></option>
                <option value="offline"><font color="#335599">Offline</font></option>
                <option value="away"><font color="#335599">Away</font></option>
                <option value="busy"><font color="#335599">Busy</font></option>
                <option value="others"><font color="#335599">Others</font></option>
            </select></font>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="topnav">
        <ul id="nav">

    <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
        <!--ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 1-1</a></li>
        </ul-->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a>
        <!--ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 2-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 2-2</a></li>                       
        </ul-->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 3-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 3-2</a></li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 4-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 4-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span-->
                <!--ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 4-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 4-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 4-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 4-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>   



    <li><a href="#">MENU 5</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 5-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 5-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span-->
                <!--ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 5-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 5-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 5-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 5-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>   


    <li><a href="#">MENU 6</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 6-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 6-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span-->
                <!--ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 6-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 6-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 6-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 6-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>


    <li><a href="#">MENU 7</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 7-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 7-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span-->
                <!--ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 7-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 7-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 7-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 7-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>   

    <li><a href="#">MENU 8</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 8-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 8-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span-->
                <!--ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 8-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 8-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 8-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 8-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>   

    <li><a href="#">MENU 9</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 9-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 9-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span-->
                <!--ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 9-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 9-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 9-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 9-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>   


    <li><a href="#">MENU 10</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 10-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 10-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 10-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 10-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 10-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 10-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">MENU 11</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 11-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 11-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 11-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 11-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 11-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 11-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>   

    <li><a href="#">MENU 12</a><span class="rarrow"> &#9660; </span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 12-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MENU 12-2</a><!--span class="rarrow"> &#9654; </span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 12-2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 12-2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 12-2-3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MENU 12-2-4</a></li>
                </ul-->
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </li>

    </ul>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    
    <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>

   </div>


   <div id="page">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        <p class="form">
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="ticket">Ticket</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="TICKET">
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <!--button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button-->

                <!--grey button for grey template-->
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

            </form>
        </p>
        <p class="form">
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="ticket">Ticket</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="TICKET">
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <!--button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button-->
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

            </form>
        </p>
        <p class="form">
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="ticket">Ticket</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="TICKET">
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <!--button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button-->
                <!--button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button-->
                <!--a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active" role="button">SUBMIT</a-->
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

            </form>
        </p>

    </div>

    <div class="maincol">   
        <div id="inner">
        <div class="t"> 

            <form class="form-inline" role="form">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="ticket">Ticket</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="TICKET">
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <!--button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button-->
                <!--button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button-->
                <!--a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg active" role="button">SUBMIT</a-->
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

            </form>
            <br/>
    <table class="smsSecond"><!--bgcolor="#4ab54d"><class="smsSecond"--     this is td bgcolor: bgcolor="#4ab54d"-->
        <tr>
             <td colspan="2" width="auto" align="center">Ticket Info</td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center"><!-- style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px;"-->
            <td>
                Ticket number
            </td>
            <td>
                HFK-864-69976
            </td>
        </tr>


        <!--even row-->
        <tr align="center"><!--style="color: #000000; font-size: 15px; background-color: #FFFFFF" --><!--background-color: #A4EAF6-->
            <td>
                Department
            </td>
            <td>
                Support
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Priority
            </td>
            <td>
                P3-Normal
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Open Date and Time
            </td>
            <td>
                2011-02-28 21:24:01          
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Close Date and Time
            </td>
            <td>
                2011-02-28 21:24:01
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Total Time
            </td>
            <td>
                00:03:09
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Ticket Spent
            </td>
            <td>
                00:02:00
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                No. of staff worked
            </td>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Ticket Status
            </td>
            <td>
                Closed
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                SLA
            </td>
            <td>
                Yes
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Type
            </td>
            <td>
                Issue
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Red Flag
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Yellow Flag
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--even row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Orange Flag
            </td>
            <td>
                0
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!--odd row-->
        <tr align="center">
            <td>
                Closed by
            </td>
            <td>
                Harsha p
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>      

</body>
</html>
```

the table with the class .smsSecond needs to be dragbale, which doen not seem to work. please help.

Comment: explain "not working"

Comment: Its working in Mozilla. I can drag your table. what exactly you want?

Comment: i am working in chrome and this is not working..

Comment: Content inside the table or entire table... There is no table inside  .smsSecond class

Comment: i mean the .smsSecond class it not draggable @Shashi

Comment: i just did edit the whole code right now. the above has the whole code i am trying to work on the draggable is not workig here

Comment: @UtkarshSingh kya uttu resolve nahi hua issue abhi tak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. Does it work for you in [this example](http://jsbin.com/UjoZiXUj/1/edit)?

Update:

Looking at updated your code, the problem is you are using two different versions of jquery.

First here:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then later:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Get rid of the script tags for jquery 1.4

Comment: i just put the whole code i am working on and the draggable() function does not seem to work here.

Comment: Can you share the whole code you are working on then?  The part you posted is working fine for me (and others).  Perhaps there is another issue that is stopping the code from executing.

Comment: i just did edit the posted code and i have put the whole code i am working on. @tankerjoe

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems OK. try to place the table in a div. then call draggable() by that div's selector(use an ID). for more help please go to [jquery draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste and work, Its absolutly woking  **Demo Here**  http://jsfiddle.net/E5HXf/

```
 <html>

    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".smsSecond").draggable();
      });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="maincol">
    <div id="inner">
        <div class="t">
            <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="ticket">Ticket</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="TICKET">
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <table class="smsSecond" style="background:grey">
                <!--bgcolor="#4ab54d"><class="smsSecond"--     this is td bgcolor: bgcolor="#4ab54d"-->
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" width="auto" align="center">Ticket Info</td>
                </tr>
                <!--odd row-->
                <tr align="center">
                    <!-- style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px;"-->
                    <td>Ticket number</td>
                    <td>HFK-864-69976</td>
                </tr>
                <!--even row-->
                <tr align="center">
                    <!--style="color: #000000; font-size: 15px; background-color: #FFFFFF" -->
                    <!--background-color: #A4EAF6-->
                    <td>Department</td>
                    <td>Support</td>
                </tr>
                <!--odd row-->
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Priority</td>
                    <td>P3-Normal</td>
                </tr>
                <!--even row-->
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>Open Date and Time</td>
                    <td>2011-02-28 21:24:01</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>



    </body>

    </html>
```